# Can't pass values from html to python cgi

Tags: python, cgi

It's about ordering pizza online.
(I just set up my local server using XAMPP and Apache and wanted to test it a little bit.)
I made a simple form in HTML and wrote a CGI script in Python, but when I type the address of the HTML file in my browser I get this error:

```
 C:\xampp\cgi-bin\Python38\pizza_s.cgi in <module>
      38 preisliste = {"Salami":6, "Di mare":6.5,
      39                 "Quattro Stagioni":7.5, "Diavolo":8.5}
 =>   40 price = list_of_prices[form["pt"].value].value                              
      41 
 preis undefined, preisliste = {'Diavolo': 8.5, 'Quattro Stagioni': 7.5, 'Salami': 6, 'Di Mare': 6.5}, form = FieldStorage(None, None, []), ].value = []
 C:\Users\Kompjuter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\cgi.py in __getitem__(self=FieldStorage(None, None, []), key='pt')
      515             if item.name == key: found.append(item)
      516         if not found:
 =>   517             raise KeyError(key)
      518         if len(found) == 1:
      519             return found[0]
 builtin KeyError = <class 'KeyError'>, key = 'pt'

 KeyError: 'pt'
     args = ('pt',)
     with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of KeyError object>
```

Here are my files:

[pizza_s.htm](https://github.com/BlackBeardedTaj/Pizza_app/blob/master/pizza_s.htm)
[pizza_s.cgi](https://github.com/BlackBeardedTaj/Pizza_app/blob/master/pizza_s.cgi)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a form element named `pt` on your initial form?

Comment: @Mike67 - Yes, a drop-down menu component, where you can choose your preferred type of pizza, is named "pt".